# iOS how to update my app's LaunchImage snapshots when it enter foreground from background by UIApplication's openURL: method

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

My purpose is when my app is at background,other app launch my app to foreground through openURL,my app can show LaunchImage first when it fade in,and the LaunchImage is the new picture ,not the old picture。

I noticed that:

In iOS7,you can only set LaunchImage at Assets.xcassets,and also it can achieve the purpose by system default.

In iOS 8 or later version,if use Assets.xcassets to set LaunchImage, when my app launch by openURL method from background to foreground,I do not see the LaunchImage,but see the snapshots picture capture by system when app enter background,

In iOS8 or later version,if use LaunchScreen.storyboard mode,we can achieve the purpose,but when you change the LaunchScreen.storyboard's content, something wrong,when you do the same action ,you will see the old launch picture,not the changed picture.

In my Xcode,I set both LaunchImage and LaunchScreen.storyboard, so it can work both in iOS7 and iOS8 or later version.but question above is appear.

my Xcode setting is like this picture:

[image]

Attention please,  kill the app,restart it you will see the changed launchImage,but my purpose is when my app is at background,other app launch my app to foreground through openURL,my app can show LaunchImage first when it fade in。

Comment: Why do you need to show the splash screen all the time?. Splash screen is usually shown when first launching the app, or after you have killed an app from background. The snapshots shown in the background mode is handled by the OS which cannot be customised.

Comment: @GoGreen
1. it is not splash screen,just LaunchImage.
2.In iOS 7,your app launch from background to foreground by openURL method,it will show launchImage first, you can try it.
3.In iOS 8, if you choose laucnScreen.storyboard to  set your LaunchImage,the same to iOS 7.but if you choose Assets.xcassets,it will not show LaunchImage when your app from background to foreground by openURL method ,only show snapshots.

Comment: @GoGreen
1. it is not splash screen,just LaunchImage.
2.In iOS 7,your app launch from background to foreground by openURL method,it will show launchImage first, you can try it.
3.In iOS 8, if you choose laucnScreen.storyboard to  set your LaunchImage,the same to iOS 7.but if you choose Assets.xcassets,it will not show LaunchImage when your app from background to foreground by openURL method ,only show snapshots.